# Hide 'close' links when modal is not open

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, popup

Ive been working on this for hours, I've tried vars, I tried hiding elements, and nothing is working and and and.. sorry for the exitement, but I'm almost down to the end,

the issue:: I have a basic javascript modal, taken from w3 schools, which has been altered slightly per my needs, 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

my javascript code is below.

What I need is, I need to hide the CLOSE span when the modal pop up is hidden,

`<span class="close">CLOSE</span>`
in other words, I dont want the close link showing at all times, thw close link should be hidden when modal os closed, and showing when modal is open.

here is my code below, can I please get a working javascript example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

````
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (let closeBtn of spans) {
  closeBtn.onclick = closeModal;
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>```
````

Comment: If you don't need that close span you can remove it from the modal.

Comment: I need it because it acts as a point of direction link, but I just want it hidden when the modal is closed and showing when the modal is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly.
Try this:

````
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  for (let closeBtn of spans) {
    closeBtn.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (let closeBtn of spans) {
  closeBtn.onclick = closeModal;
  closeBtn.style.display = 'none';
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";

  for (let closeBtn of spans) {
    closeBtn.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    for (let closeBtn of spans) {
      closeBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
</script>```
````

It would be better if we put out the repeating code in separate functions.

Answer (score 2):

Just add to your show/hide function appropriate hide/show span:

Change closeModal() to:

```
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  spans[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

and change btn.onclick to:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  spans[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

I see you are using `getElementsByClassName()` which is returning (always) array of results (thats why I'm using index ([0]) to access found element). If I were you I would add new **id** to the span so you can be sure what you target.

Have a look at [Changing HTML style](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: thank you, but the problem was, this solution did the opposite, and the button disapeared when the model was open an appeared when modal was closed.

Comment: can you try to fix this and make it where the close link hides when the modal is closed and shows when the modal is open?

Comment: Weeell I cooould but that would do no good for you. Try experimenting and find solution by yourself, it's just two ctrl +c, ctrl + v